# Maxima problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

this question is off a textbook, and I've been having a lot of trouble with it:

"A window consists of a rectangle surmounted by a semi-circle having its diameter the width of the rectangle. If the perimeter of the window is $t$ meters, find the greatest possible area of the window."

The final answer is:

$t^2 / 2(pi + 4)$

Could someone please explain how to do this step by step?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to find the perimeter of a rectangle, of a semicircle, and how to find the area of each?

Comment: The old "Norman window" problem -- seems like _everyone_ steals this to use in their textbook...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We set things up, and leave the differentiation and conclusion to you.

Let us explore what happens if we let the radius be $x$. Then the curvy part of the semi-circle has perimeter $\pi x$. The base of the window has length $2x$. Since the whole perimeter is $t$, the two sides have combined length $t-\pi x-2x$. It follows that each side of the window has length
$$\frac{t-\pi x-2x}{2}.$$

Next we find a formula for the area $A(x)$ of the window.

The semi-circle has area $\frac{\pi}{2}x^2$.

The rectangular part of the window has area $(2x)\frac{t-\pi x-2x}{2}=x(t-\pi x -2x)$. It follows that
$$A(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}x^2 +x(t-\pi x -2x).$$
Now do the usual thing: find where $A'(x)=0$.

For completeness, we have to check  whether the maximum is at an end-point, or alternately look at the sign of $A'(x)$ when $A'(x)\ne 0$.

Comment: Hi again, you really helped.
However, I got to the point where I found the derivative of A, and when it equals 0. I got: $t-πx-4x$, but that's not the answer. What do I do?

Comment: You were asked for the maximum **area**. Put the derivative equal to $0$, solve for $x$. We get $x=\frac{t}{\pi+4}$. That's the "best" choice for $x$. Now substitute this value of $x$ in the formula for $A(x)$.

Comment: OH right. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Often such a question asks for the best radius, or the best base. This time they asked for the biggest **value** of the function.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If the width $=a$ unit, the height is $=b$ unit,

the perimeter $=\frac{\pi a}2+2b+a=t\implies b=\frac{2t-(\pi+2)a}4$

So, the total area $=\frac{\pi\left(\frac a2\right)^2}2+a\cdot b=\frac{\pi\left(\frac a2\right)^2}2+a\cdot\frac{2t-(\pi+2)a}4 =f(a)$ (say)

Use [Second derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test)

Comment: perimeter of semi circle is $$\frac{πa}{2}$$